# WPF TreeView - selecting and expanding nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I think my question is rather basic, but I can't find an answer:
I have a TreeView, and I can't figure out how to monitor nodes' selection. I have breakpoints at the handlers for both `TreeView.SelectedItemChanged` and `TreeViewItem.Expanded`. When a node is expanded I do see the `TreeViewItem.Expanded` handler at work, but when clicking on a node, none of those events are fired.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

TreeView code:

```
    <TreeView Name="TestsTree" Height="Auto" MinHeight="50" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeNodes, Mode=TwoWay}" TreeViewItem.Expanded="TestsTreeExpanded" TreeView.SelectedItemChanged="TestsTreeSelectedItemChanged">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeNodes, Mode=TwoWay}" DataType="{x:Type TestExplorer:FolderTreeNode}">
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

**Edit:**
I've tried using `TreeViewItem.Selected` but it's the same - when I click on a node's name there's no reaction, though when I click at the expansion area, both `TreeViewItem.Selected` and `TreeViewItem.Selected` are fired. Any explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't put a `TreeViewItem` in your `DataTemplate`. The `TreeViewItem` is created automatically by the `TreeView`. The `DataTemplate` defines the *content* of the `TreeViewItem`, not the `TreeViewItem` itself. Now you have two nested `TreeViewItems`, which is probably why it doesn't work as expected. Try that instead:

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeNodes, Mode=TwoWay}" DataType="{x:Type TestExplorer:FolderTreeNode}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: This solved it! Thanks! I should probably read more about templates, I saw this usage in a web page that explained how to bind a tree to an `ObservableCollection` and thought it would work...

Answer (score 1):

Try `TreeViewItem.Selected` Event instead of the `TreeView.SelectedItemChanged`